# fraction of an opposite side of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

This trigonometry question is a result of @Butane's answer to how to set up the Hamiltonian for the following problem, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/594055/plane-pendulum-at-an-angle-goldstein-12-11/

The original set up is as follows:
[image]

the motivation behind finding h is for the gravitational potential energy $U=mgh$.

As per Butane's suggestion, I adopt the following set up

[image]

Where from this Butane's derives $h=(H-A \cos(\theta))\sin(\alpha)$

In an effort to derive this, I add one variable in the geometry

[image]

where I am confident in the following trig equations

\begin{eqnarray}
h &=& H- A \cos \theta \\
\frac{h}{x} &=& \sin(\alpha) \\
\frac{H}{A+x} &=& \sin(\alpha)
\end{eqnarray}

I am unsure how to derive Butane's result above.

Comment: H is the slanted line which passes through support point and the intersection of planes intersection with horizontal surface that is the problem for the above calculation the reason is the bad explanation done by myself sorry for that.

Comment: I added photos to original answer https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDIW-O_qldjxptHkk03nlZn7i35JyP09/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UC4mFP8w0DJdgSBvmDo5YruQp8BYsP47/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I guess now it is okay